# Unable to check if image uploaded by wp_image_editor exists using file_exists function

Tags: theme-development, uploads, wp-filesystem, file-manager

I am developing a podcast theme where i have a form that allows the user to upload their podcast cover arts. The Podcast cover art’s dimension should fall under 1400×1400 and 3000×3000 since we are following iTune’s regulations.

Since such big files will impact the page load speed of the site i wanna resize the uploaded image to a smaller size, say 250×250 so that we can use that to display on our web pages.

I have used `WP_Image_Editor::resize` function to resize the uploaded image and `WP_Image_Editor::save` function to save it. It actually worked. I now have two different images with two different dimensions.
Since a lot of our user’s have already posted their podcast with the bigger images, i simply cannot exclusively show the compressed version. Instead **i wanna check if a compressed version exists or not and show the image accordingly**.

I have used **PHP**’s `file_exists` function to check for the compressed version of the images. But it seems, it always returns false in the case of compressed images. But i can access it through the browser by typing in the full address.

```
file_exists('path/to/original_image'); = true
file_exists('path/to/compressed_image'); = false
```

I have used `wp_handle_upload` to upload the original image but `wp_image_editor` class to resize and save the compressed one. So there must be something different with these two functions that’s causing this issue.

I have hosted this on wordpress.com and when i try to access the compressed files (which are inside the upload folder) through **FTP** i can't see them, but are accessible through browser.

Do you guys have any idea, how i can get over this ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

#### EDIT - MORE INFO

This is the code i am using actually,

```php
if ( isset( $_FILES ) && isset( $_FILES['podcast_cover'] ) ) {
    
    // Validating the file extension first,
  
    // And then the Image Mime Type

    $image = wp_get_image_editor( $_FILES['podcast_cover']['tmp_name'] );
    $size = $image->get_size();

    // Validating the size ...
    if ( $size['width'] < 1400 ) {
        global $registration_errors;
        $registration_errors->add( 'podcast_cover', 'The image should be atleast 1400x1400 in size.' );
        return $this->redirect_back_to_form();
    } elseif ($size['width'] > 3000) {
        global $registration_errors;
        $registration_errors->add( 'podcast_cover', 'The image should not be over 3000x3000 in size.' );
        return $this->redirect_back_to_form();
    }

    // Uploading the main one,
    $override = ['test_form' => false];
    $uploaded = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES['podcast_cover'], $override );

    // Now compressing and saving the alternative one
    $pathinfo = pathinfo( $uploaded['url'] );
    $image = wp_get_image_editor( $uploaded['url'] );
    $image->resize( 250, 250 );
    $image->save( $pathinfo['dirname'] . '/' . $pathinfo['filename'] . '-300x300.' . $pathinfo['extension'] );

}
```

***These are the images i am referring to actually***

`Original Image : https://torontopodcaststudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/my-podcast-cover.jpg`

`Compressed Image : https://torontopodcaststudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/my-podcast-cover-300x300.jpg`

[image: ftp screenshot]

Comment: There's no reason `file_exists()` wouldn't work for compressed images. You likely have the path incorrect. If they don't appear via FTP then you mustn't be saving them where you think you are, or are connecting by FTP to the incorrect site. There's no information  in you question about how you're uploading the images, or where they're supposed to be located, so it's hard to help. Also, you say you "hosted this on wordpress.org", but wordpress.org is not a web host. Do you mean wordpress.com? Who is your web host?

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't use `add_image_size` so that WP would automatically create the extra files on upload? Then you could use a regenerate thumnails type plugin to apply it retroactively. You could even simplify it further by using the featured image functionality, and that would make a lot of other things automatically use the cover image too

Comment: Hi @JacobPeattie Thanks for the quick response. Sorry, the site is hosted on WordPress.com. I am absolutely sure that i am trying to access the right path via the FTP. As i mentioned, i am uploading the original image using `wp_handle_upload` and then using `WP_ImageEditor` class to `resize` and `save` the image. Anyway, let me edit the question a bit so that i can make it a little more clear.

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell i am actually saving the data to a custom table, so i'm afraid i cannot use the Featured Image functionality. I originally thought about using `Image Intervention` for the resize, but when i came across `WP_Image_Editor` i though this would be a simple solution.

Comment: That does not prevent you from using standard attachments and image sizes though, by using `add_image_size` WordPress will automatically create images at the required size, even cropping them if you tell it to. It's a 1 liner for each extra size, much easier than handling raw uploads and resizing manually. You could eliminate most of your upload handling code and replace it with a 1 line sideload API call, `wp_handle_sideload`, the attachment system already does all of this for you so there's no need to  rebuild it from scratch. Just store the ID of the attachment and ask for the size you want

Comment: As an aside, I see there are redirects, are you bootstrapping WordPress in a dedicated PHP file and submitting forms directly to a PHP file in your plugin/theme then redirecting once processed? If so that's not how forms in WordPress work, and could be a big security hole in your site

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell, that's a great suggestion, lemme try those functions. I would love to keep my code as simple as possible. Regarding the redirects, i am submitting the form to admin-post.php thanks to this article [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/handling-post-requests-the-wordpress-way/). And if the form has errors, i am redirecting the users back to the original form with the errors serialized and stored in a session variable. And on the page load i am using `init` action to check for the errors and un-serialize and create an error object with it, so that i can access it within the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used your exact code on a local test site I was unable to save the resized image. This is because you're passing a URL to [wp_get_image_editor()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_image_editor/) instead of a path. You're also passing a URL to `pathinfo()`, which also requires a path.

```
$pathinfo = pathinfo( $uploaded['url'] );
$image = wp_get_image_editor( $uploaded['url'] );
```

The above lines need to be:

```
$pathinfo = pathinfo( $uploaded['file'] );
$image = wp_get_image_editor( $uploaded['file'] );
```

This is because the `file` key of the array returned by `wp_handle_upload()` contains the path to the file, which is what each function above requires.

I can't explain why you're able to access the 300x300 version in the browser though. That didn't happen to me when I tested. It could be something specific to the WordPress.com hosting environment.

Comment: Hi, thanks, that was the problem. I was such an idiot to pass in the URL there. It is working fine now. Sadly, I doesn't have much reputation to up vote your answer though. It is very strange how i was able to access the image then, even though it was not present in the upload folder. Might be something related to the WordPress hosting as you mentioned.